# Limpar Conteúdo de Célula (A2) se o valor de outra celular(A1) for igual a um texto especifico

Tags: script, google-sheets

Por favor alguém pode me ajudar com o seguinte caso:

Tenho uma planilha no Google Sheets;

Preciso de um script para limpar o conteúdo de uma determinada célula (A1) SE o texto de outra célula (A2) for igual a um texto especifico ("VALOR TABELADO")

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.
Rodrigo Wolff

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução simples, seria utilizar uma coluna auxiliar, com uma função **IF** e que serviria para algum tipo de calculo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Prezado, bom dia!

Segue resolução da demanda proposta:

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var s = ss.getActiveSheet()

function limparCelula() {
  let valorB1 = s.getRange('B1').getValue()

  if (valorB1 == 'VALOR TABELADO'){

    s.getRange('A1').clear()
  }
}
```

Lembrando que também é possível utilizar `s.getRange('A1').setValue('')`  dentro do bloco `if` para não perder a formatação da célula.